# Starting bounty by the answerer himself with reason "Reward existing answer"

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, accepted-answer

I am just wondering after seeing this question : [PHP JSON Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415301/php-json-special-character) , which has a bounty worthy of 100 reputation, with a reason showing as "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty." But as you will see there is only one answer (already accepted) which is posted by the bounty owner himself.

As far as know, the bounty owner cannot award himself as mentioned in [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) wiki. So I am not sure, how this is going to "Reward existing answer". Can anyone please explain what am I missing here?

Comment: A lot of people simply don't understand how Bounties work... clearly, this is one of them... alternately, he could have picked the wrong explanation. Either way, only that guy can tell you.

Comment: I am sure that he hasn't picked the wrong explanation, because the question is answered by him and accepted by OP and there is no scope for better answers by others.

Comment: Maybe he's just counting on getting a higher answer score to partially offset the bounty cost. If he got it up to +10, that would give him a bronze and a silver badge, and therefore also another hat, for the cost of 40 rep or so. Some people would consider that a reasonable transaction.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, Yeah, I was also thinking about that. But is it a legitimate way of achieving score / badges (unnecessarily open a bounty)?

Comment: Getting attention is the basic purpose of a bounty, and votes come from attention * quality, so it seems OK. If the user really didn't have that in mind, it might even be OK to offer a refund, since the bounty will have no other purpose.

Comment: Maybe they were counting on the ensuing confusion resulting in a post on meta.SE, leading to more attention from other sites in the network.

Comment: @trichoplax, Haha! Anyhow, he is successful! :)